# Word Add-in Inserting table (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ms-word, add-in, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to write a add-in for word 2016 using the javascript api. The add-in is supposed to have a button that inserts tables but I can't quite get it to work.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
        // Create a proxy object for the document body.
        var body = context.document.body;

        body.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end, [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]);

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(function (e) {

        console.log(e.message);
    })
```

Here is the method I have to test it. Whenever I activate it, it causes word to hang for a moment and then does nothing.I have also already made sure that the problem has nothing to do with the button that runs the method .If anyone knows why or how to fix it I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was because of the build version of word that I was using was not supporting the inserttable method, so updating word was the fix for the problem